# Plot filledcurve with variable transparency

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot a function in gnuplot with filledcurve, but having a variable transparency.

To be clear, consider the following example:

http://www.gnuplot.info/demo_canvas_4.7/rgba_lines.html

In this case, the arrow angle (an integer variable) is used as parameter to define the alpha channel. Is it possible to do the same using a function instead?

PS: I am aware that I'll probably will need to convert to an integer, as the alpha channel are bits...

Comment: What would the transparency level depend on? Can you show an example of the effect you would like to achieve?

Comment: @user8153 One trivial example would be to plot a semicircle in which the transparency level at each point depends on its distance to the radius.

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43521591/7932936) work?

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach to achieve your goal is plotting several highly transparent (e.g. alpha `0xef`) scaled areas on top of each other. For this, the areas need to be easily scalable from a center point, e.g. like circles, ellipses, squares, triangles, etc.

In order to tune the results, you need to play with:

- `N`: number of areas you are stacking. If `N` is small you will see steps, if `N` is large plotting will be slow (and resulting graph maybe large in case of vector format)
- `Alpha`: transparency of objects. In order to fade it out the value should be high, e.g. >`0xee`.
- `R()`: function of scaling radius of areas, e.g. `(real(i)/N)` would be linear

This question could also be of interest: [Gnuplot: transparency of data points when using palette](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60250928/7295599)

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.0.0)

```
### cirles with variable radial transparency
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 60
    # x,y,r,color
    plot '+' u (rand(0)*100):(rand(0)*100):(rand(0)*10+1):(int(rand(0)*0xffffff)) w table
unset table

set style fill solid 1.0 noborder
set samples 100
set key noautotitle
set angle degrees

N            = 50
Alpha        = 0xef
R(col,n)     = column(col)*(real(n)/N)**2
myColor(col) = (Alpha<<24) + int(column(col))

plot for [n=1:N] $Data u 1:2:(R(3,n)):(myColor(4)) w circle lc rgb var
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]