# Gnuplot: transparency of data points when using palette

Tags: gnuplot, transparency, alpha, palette

Is there a way to plot transparent data points when using palette?

I currently have the following code:

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.2 noborder
set palette rgb 22,13,-22
plot 'mydata.dat' u 1:2:3 ps 0.3 palette
```

My feeling is that transparency is overwritten by the arguments of the plot command.

Comment: `set style fill transparent` applies to fill areas, like the facets making up a pm3d surface or the interior of a polygon or the `filledcurves` plot style.  It does not apply to lines and points.  Your plot command appears to use points since you give a pointsize option, although the set of commands is incomplete so I am not 100% certain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gnuplot: How to make scatter plots with transparent points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532568/gnuplot-how-to-make-scatter-plots-with-transparent-points)

Comment: Thanks @Friedrich. It doesn't answer the question because I cannot see an easy way to use palette at the same time. Still useful!

Comment: Ah! I also need this: a palette where all colors have some level of transparency! It's rare to hit something missing in gnuplot.

Comment: I just asked for this gnuplot feature on sourceforge,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to plot transparent data points when using palette?

If you check `help palette` you will not find (or I overlooked) a statement about transparency in the palette. It looks like you can set the palette in different ways for `RGB`, but not for `ARGB` (A=alpha channel for transparency). So, I assume it is not possible with palette to have transparency (please correct me if I am wrong).
As workaround you have to set your transparency "manually" by setting the color with some transparency.
You can find the formulae behind the palettes by typing `show palette rgbformulae`.

The following examples creates a plot with random point positions in `xrange[0:1]` and `yrange[0:1]` and random points size (from 2 to 6) and random transparency (from `0x00` to `0xff`). The color is determined by `x` according to your "manual palette". I hope you can adapt this example to your needs.

**Code:**

```
### "manual" palette with transparency
reset session

# These are the rgb formulae behind palette 22,13,-22
set angle degrees
r(x) = 3*x-1 < 0 ? 0: (3*x-1 > 1) ? 1 : 3*x-1
g(x) = sin(180*x)
b(x) = 1-(3*x-1) < 0 ? 0: (1-(3*x-1) > 1) ? 1 : 1-(3*x-1)

set xrange [0:1]
set yrange[-0.1:1.1]

RandomSize(n) = rand(0)*4+2              # random size from 2 to 6
RandomTransp(n) = int(rand(0)*0xff)<<24  # random transparency from 0x00 to 0xff
myColor(x) = (int(r(x)*0xff)<<16) + (int(g(x)*0xff)<<8) + int(b(x)*0xff) + RandomTransp(0)

set samples 200
plot '+' u (x=rand(0)):(rand(0)):(RandomSize(0)):(myColor(x)) w p pt 7 ps var lc rgb var not

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Works for me. Thanks also for the background information.

Comment: A follow-up comment: When printing `myColor(x)` this sometimes results in negative values. This is probably because at calculation or at printing level this results in a signed integer. Seems to work fine, but maybe @theozh could help clarify?

Comment: I don't know how exactly you are using it. In my case `x` in `myColor(x)` is only for `0<=x<=1`. There should not be negative values with the formulae `r(x),g(x),b(x)` given above.

Comment: If I print a few sample values, e.g., repeatedly execute `print(myColor(0.5))` I get negative values. Gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2. It seems to work and I assume it's a conversion between signed and unsigned under the hood, but I thought I'd mention.

Comment: apparently, gnuplot is interpreting it right as unsigned. Just for checking, try: `do for [i=1:100] { print sprintf("%08x % 11u", myColor(0.5), myColor(0.5))}`, which will print 100 random colors and if you format them as `%u`, they are all positive ;-). Btw, in the gnuplot documentation I can't find format specifier `%u` in the list.

Answer (score 3):

### New answer for Dev version 5.5

The new function `set colormap` allows to define a transparent palette. First, one defines the fully opaque palette in the usual way, then creates a copy of it and adds transparency to all points:

```
set palette rgb 22,13,-22
set colormap new MYPALETTE
transparency = 0.5
do for [i=1:|MYPALETTE|] {MYPALETTE[i] = MYPALETTE[i] + (int(transparency*0xff)<<24)}
func(x,y) = x*y
splot func(x,y) w pm3d fillcolor palette MYPALETTE
```

[image]

Of course, this will also work for points, the command in your case will be
`plot 'mydata.dat' u 1:2:3 ps 0.3 lc palette MYPALETTE`