# Adding transparency to the points in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, transparency, point

I am trying to visualize a block of two different color particles and I want to add transparency to the points. I write a file (cubo.d) with this data (example):

```
1   1   1   ar
1   1   2   ar
1   2   1   ar
1   2   2   ar
2   1   1   ab
2   1   2   ab
2   2   1   ab
2   2   2   ab
```

And then I read it with this code in gnuplot:

```
set border 0
unset tics
unset key
set view equal xyz
set style fill transparent solid 0.2 noborder
spin(name) = name[1:2] eq "ar" ? 0xcdca00 : name [1:2] eq "ab" ? 0x000000 : 0x888888
splot 'cubo.d' using 1:2:3:(spin(strcol(4))) w p pt 5 ps 2
```

But the points doesn't have transparency.
I tried adding  `fs solid 0.2` and also `lc rgb 0x888888` after `w p pt 5 ps 2` but those doesn't work either.
[image: The four yellow particles are hidding part of the black particles behind]

The four yellow particles are hidding part of the black particles behind

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gnuplot: transparency of data points when using palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60250928/gnuplot-transparency-of-data-points-when-using-palette)

Comment: I saw that question but I couldn't get the answer from there. Thank you anyway, if I knew a little more about gnuplot probably I could have got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheme for transparent colors is

```
lc rgb 0xaarrggbb
```

Check `help colorspec`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code like this, on the fifth line:
"spin(name) = name[1:2] eq "ar" ? 0x88cdca00 : name [1:2] eq "ab" ? 0x88000000 : 0x888888"
And it works.